How to chain async monads in TypeScript
I recently made this class to treat error as a value in typescript, i want to do in a way that you could chain methods that expects and returns Response
return-pattern.ts:
// import { APIErrors } from "../errors/api-errors";

type SuccessResponse<T> = [null, T];
type Err = {message: string, stack: string, name: string}
type ErrResponse = [Err, null];

export type HandleResponse<T> = SuccessResponse<T> | ErrResponse;

export class Response<T> {
  private _data: T | null
  private _err: Err | null

  private constructor (data:T | null ,err: Err | null) {
    this._data = data
    this._err = err
  }

  static success<T>(data: T): Response<T> {
    return new Response(data, null)
  }

  static err<T>(err: Err): Response<T> {
    return new Response(null, err) as Response<T>
  }

  bind<R>(func: (res: Response<T>) => Response<R> ): Response<R> {
    if (this._err) {
      return Response.err(this._err) as Response<R>;
    }

    return func(this);
  }

  async bindAsync<R>(func: (res: Response<T>) => Promise<Response<R>>): Promise<Response<R>> {
    if (this._err) {
      return Response.err(this._err) as Response<R>;
    }
    

    return await func(this);
  }


  divide(): HandleResponse<T> {
    if (this._data) return [null, this._data];
    return [this._err as Err, null];
  }

}


Use case example:
// ...
async function chaining() {
  
  const addTen = async (res: Response<number>) => {
    const num = res.data() as number;
    return Response.success(num + 10);
  }

  return  Response.success(5)
    .bindAsync(addTen)
}

async function chainingMoreThanOne() {
  
  const addTen = async (res: Response<number>) => {
    const num = res.data() as number;
    return Response.success(num + 10);
  }

  return  Response.success(5)
    .bindAsync(addTen)
    .bindAsync(addTen) // Here you got a error

}



main()

And the error is:
Property 'bindAsync' does not exist on type 'Promise<Response<createProductDTO>>'.

How would I do this bindAsync in a way that a can chain it indefinetily?
====================================================================================================================================

apparently you need to await parseProductDTO as it returns a promise of the response type

Please [edit] to make your code a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now you reference undeclared/private types/values so we see a bunch of errors unrelated to your question.

@jcalz done!!!!

Your basic bind method is not monadic. The callback should expect a T, not a Response<T>. Fix that first.

You probably should not mix synchronous and asynchronous methods in the same class. An asynchronous Response will never be able to implement a divide that synchronously returns a HandleResponse, it'll always return a promise in the end. Build a separate AsyncResponse class instead. It'll essentially be a thin wrapper around a Promise.
